# Paypal (Option + Value)

Tags: html, api, paypal

I have a simple Paypal question.

How do i make a button which add 100 USD (Example) And a random name for the purchase.

This html might help

```
<select name="T-shirt from blablabla">
<option>Do not add</option>
<option value="100">Do add</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script to modify the amount, based on the user selection.  Depending on how simple you wanted to keep it, you could just create a drop down menu, and have that menu set the price.  Otherwise if you are going to have different options that modify the amount, you would need to use a script.  Below is an example I have used in the past with different selections that modify the amount.

```
<!-- Start of Script -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
//
function Dollar (val) {  // force to valid dollar amount
var str,pos,rnd=0;
  if (val < .995) rnd = 1;  // for old Netscape browsers
  str = escape (val*1.0 + 0.005001 + rnd);  // float, round, escape
  pos = str.indexOf (".");
  if (pos > 0) str = str.substring (rnd, pos + 3);
  return str;
}

var amt,des,obj,val,op1a,op1b,op2a,op2b,itmn;

function ChkTok (obj1) {
var j,tok,ary=new Array ();       // where we parse
  ary = val.split (" ");          // break apart
  for (j=0; j<ary.length; j++) {  // look at all items
// first we do single character tokens...
    if (ary[j].length < 2) continue;
    tok = ary[j].substring (0,1); // first character
    val = ary[j].substring (1);   // get data
    if (tok == "@") amt = val * 1.0;
    if (tok == "+") amt = amt + val*1.0;
    if (tok == "%") amt = amt + (amt * val/100.0);
     if (tok == "-") amt = amt - val*1.0;
    if (tok == "#") {             // record item number
      if (obj1.item_number) obj1.item_number.value = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // zap this array element
    }
// Now we do 3-character tokens...
    if (ary[j].length < 4) continue;
    tok = ary[j].substring (0,3); // first 3 chars
    val = ary[j].substring (3);   // get data
    if (tok == "s1=") {           // value for shipping
      if (obj1.shipping)  obj1.shipping.value  = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
    }
    if (tok == "s2=") {           // value for shipping2
      if (obj1.shipping2) obj1.shipping2.value = val;
      ary[j] = "";                // clear it out
    }
  }
  val = ary.join (" ");           // rebuild val with what's left
}

function StorVal () {
var tag;
  tag = obj.name.substring (obj.name.length-2);  // get flag
  if      (tag == "1a") op1a = op1a + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "1b") op1b = op1b + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "2a") op2a = op2a + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "2b") op2b = op2b + " " + val;
  else if (tag == "3i") itmn = itmn + " " + val;
  else if (des.length == 0) des = val;
  else des = des + ", " + val;
}

function ReadForm (obj1, tst) { // Read the user form
var i,j,pos;
  amt=0;des="";op1a="";op1b="";op2a="";op2b="";itmn="";
  if (obj1.baseamt) amt  = obj1.baseamt.value*1.0;  // base amount
  if (obj1.basedes) des  = obj1.basedes.value;  // base description
  if (obj1.baseon0) op1a = obj1.baseon0.value;  // base options
  if (obj1.baseos0) op1b = obj1.baseos0.value;
  if (obj1.baseon1) op2a = obj1.baseon1.value;
  if (obj1.baseos1) op2b = obj1.baseos1.value;
  if (obj1.baseitn) itmn = obj1.baseitn.value;
  for (i=0; i<obj1.length; i++) {     // run entire form
    obj = obj1.elements[i];           // a form element
    if (obj.type == "select-one") {   // just selects
      if (obj.name == "quantity" ||
          obj.name == "amount") continue;
      pos = obj.selectedIndex;        // which option selected
      val = obj.options[pos].value;   // selected value
      ChkTok (obj1);                  // check for any specials

      if (obj.name == "on0" ||        // let this go where it wants
          obj.name == "os0" ||
          obj.name == "on1" ||
          obj.name == "os1") continue;

      StorVal ();

    } else
    if (obj.type == "checkbox" ||     // just get checkboxex
        obj.type == "radio") {        //  and radios
      if (obj.checked) {
        val = obj.value;              // the value of the selection
        ChkTok (obj1);
        StorVal ();
      }
    } else
    if (obj.type == "select-multiple") {  //one or more
      for (j=0; j<obj.options.length; j++) {  // run all options
        if (obj.options[j].selected) {
          val = obj.options[j].value; // selected value (default)
          ChkTok (obj1);
          StorVal ();
        }
      }
    } else
    if ((obj.type == "text" ||        // just read text,
         obj.type == "textarea") &&
         obj.name != "tot" &&         //  but not from here
         obj.name != "quantity") {
      val = obj.value;                // get the data
      if (val == "" && tst) {         // force an entry
        alert ("Enter data for " + obj.name);
        return false;
      }
      StorVal ();
    }
  }
// Now summarize stuff we just processed, above
  if (op1a.length > 0) obj1.on0.value = op1a;
  if (op1b.length > 0) obj1.os0.value = op1b;
  if (op2a.length > 0) obj1.on1.value = op2a;
  if (op2b.length > 0) obj1.os1.value = op2b;
  if (itmn.length > 0) obj1.item_number.value = itmn;
  obj1.item_name.value = des;
  obj1.amount.value = Dollar (amt);
  if (obj1.tot) obj1.tot.value = "$" + Dollar (amt);
}
//-->
</script>
<!-- End of Script -->



Insulin Pump Pouch - Base Price $29.95 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
onsubmit="this.target = '_self';
          return ReadForm(this, true);">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxx@ccaples.com"><!--your email address goes here -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">

<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-ii/cart-button-w-options">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-ii/cart-button-w-options">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-ii/cart-button-w-options">

<input type="hidden" name="baseamt" value="00">
<input type="hidden" name="basedes" value="Insulin Pump Pouch">

<input type="hidden" name="baseon0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="baseos0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="baseon1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="baseos1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="baseitn" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="os1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">

Waist Measurement:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="Size" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);">
  <option value="Please Choose" selected>Please Choose</option>
  <option value="18 inch Waist @29.95">18 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="19 inch Waist @29.95">19 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="20 inch Waist @29.95">20 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="21 inch Waist @29.95">21 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="22 inch Waist @29.95">22 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="23 inch Waist @29.95">23 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="24 inch Waist @29.95">24 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="25 inch Waist @29.95">25 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="26 inch Waist @29.95">26 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="27 inch Waist @29.95">27 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="28 inch Waist @29.95">28 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="29 inch Waist @29.95">29 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="30 inch Waist @29.95">30 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="31 inch Waist @29.95">31 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="32 inch Waist @29.95">32 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="32 inch Waist @29.95">32 inch Waist - $29.95</option>
  <option value="33 inch Waist @30.95">33 inch Waist - $30.95</option>
  <option value="34 inch Waist @30.95">34 inch Waist - $30.95</option>
  <option value="35 inch Waist @30.95">35 inch Waist - $30.95</option>
  <option value="36 inch Waist @30.95">36 inch Waist - $30.95</option>
  <option value="37 inch Waist @30.95">37 inch Waist - $30.95</option>
  <option value="38 inch Waist @31.95">38 inch Waist - $31.95</option>
  <option value="39 inch Waist @31.95">39 inch Waist - $31.95</option>
  <option value="40 inch Waist @31.95">40 inch Waist - $31.95</option>
  <option value="41 inch Waist @31.95">41 inch Waist - $31.95</option>
  <option value="42 inch Waist @31.95">42 inch Waist - $31.95</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<INPUT type="hidden" name="on0" value="Pump Model">Select your Insulin Pump Model:
<SELECT name="os0">
<OPTION value="Animas 1200 Series" selected>Animas 1200 Series</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Animas 20000 Series">Animas 20000 Series</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Cozmo">Cozmo</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Cozmo w.Cozmonitor">Cozmo w.Cozmonitor</OPTION>
<OPTION value="MiniMed 500 Series">MiniMed 500 Series</OPTION>
<OPTION value="MiniMed 700 Series">MiniMed 700 Series</OPTION>
<OPTION value="AccuCheck">AccuCheck</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<br><br>

<INPUT type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style">Zipper or Velcro:
<SELECT name="os1">
<OPTION value="Right Zip/Velcro In" selected>Right Zip/Velcro In</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Left Zip/Velcro In">Left Zip/Velcro In</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Right Zip/Velcro Out">Right Zip/Velcro Out</OPTION>
<OPTION value="Left Zip/Velcro Out">Left Zip/Velcro Out</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<br><br>

Extra Options:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="Options" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);">
  <option value="Please Choose" selected>Please Choose</option>
  <option value="Add a Window +3.00">Add a Window + $3.00</option>
  <option value="Make Pouch Padded +3.00">Make Pouch Padded + $3.00</option>
  <option value="Add Extra Velcro on Belt +3.00">Add Extra Velcro on Belt + $3.00</option>
  <option value="Make it a Double Pouch +10.00">Make it a Double Pouch + $10.00</option>
  <option value="Make it a Belt Loop Pouch +0.00">Make it a Belt Loop Pouch + $0.00</option>
  <option value="Make it a Hook Pouch +1.00">Make it a Hook Pouch + $1.00</option>
  <option value="Make it a Vertical Pouch +5.00">Make it a Vertical Pouch + $5.00</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<input type="image" src="http://www.ccaples.com/mts/scripts/cart.gif" name="submit" alt="cart add">
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Total Cost &gt; 
<input class="nbor" type="text" name="tot" size="8" value="$0.00">
 &nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type    = "button" 
       value   = "Reset FORM" 
       onclick = "this.form.reset();">

</form>
```